# How can i get the remove facebook application event or request?

Tags: facebook, api

if the Facebook user remove my application? how can i get event when he do that? is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your-app-id]/advanced

Look for: Deauthorize Callback:

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ about 60% down under "App Deauthorization".

> When a user of your app removes it in the App Dashboard or blocks the
>   app in the News Feed, your app can be notified by specifying a
>   Deauthorize Callback URL in the Developer App. During app removal we
>   will send an HTTP POST request containing a single parameter,
>   signed_request, which contains the user id (UID) of the user that just
>   removed your app. You will not receive an user access token in this
>   request and all existing user access tokens will be automatically
>   expired.